# Replace all but last instance of specified character

Tags: regex, vb.net

If I have a string like

```
10,000kg crane,21
```

how should I strip all commas but the last to get

```
10000kg crane,21
```

I'm thinking this is a regular expression problem.

Comment: So you want the output to be 10000kg crane,21?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Another approach, which may perform much faster than a RegEx solution:

```
Dim s As String = "10,000kg crane,21"
Dim result As String = New StringBuilder(s).Replace(",", String.Empty, 0,
    s.LastIndexOf(","c)).ToString()
```

The gist is that it will replace all occurrences of "," with an empty string between the first character and the index of the last ",".

I did some benchmarks running this and [the proposed RegEx solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116625/74757) 1,000,000 times each; on my laptop, without compiling the RegEx, this solution is about seven (7) times faster. If you do compile the RegEx, it's still about twice as fast.

Comment: Thanks - this is much easier to maintain.

Answer (score 11):

It can be done with regular expressions by using a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). You want to replace the commas that have at least one comma after them. The only comma for which this lookahead will fail is the last one.

Try this:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, ",(?=.*?,)", "")
```

See it working online: [ideone](http://ideone.com/1zgzz)

Comment: +1, although you might want to add a `(?s)` at the start in case the string contains newlines.

Answer (score 1):

A none regex approach:

```
Dim text = "10,000kg crane,21"
Dim parts = text.Split(","c).Reverse
Dim result = String.Join("", parts.Skip(1).Reverse) & "," & parts.First
```

Answer (score 0):

An uglier, yet valid alternative approach:

```
    Dim strResult As String = Replace(Mid(strTarget, 1, strTarget.LastIndexOf(",")), ",", String.Empty) & _
                              Microsoft.VisualBasic.Right(strTarget, Len(strTarget) - strTarget.LastIndexOf(","))
```