# How do I remove periods from file names using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script in PowerShell that searches folders for files containing unnecessary periods, then mass removes the periods from the file names.

ex.    Example.File.doc ---> ExampleFile.doc

Whenever I run the code, the console returns the following: "Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string."

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
$files = get-childitem -path "C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX" -Recurse 
foreach($file in $files) {

    if($file.Name -match ".") {
        $newName = $file.Name -ireplace (".", "")
        Rename-Item $file.FullName $newName
        Write-Host "Renamed" $file.Name "to $newName at Location:" $file.FullName
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One thing about string replacing: When I tried your example without escaping the period, it didn't replace anything and returned nothing (empty string), which I believe answers your "Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string"

This worked by escaping the period. Also, it works with or without the parenthesis.

```
$string = "the.file.name"

$newstring = $string -ireplace "\.", ""
// output: thefilename
$newstring.length
// output: 11

$othernewstring = $string -ireplace ("\.", "")
// output: thefilename
$othernewstring.length
// output: 11

// What the OP tried
$donothingstring = $string -ireplace (".", "")
// output:
$donothingstring.length
// output: 0
```

There is some additional information on string replace here, just for reference https://vexx32.github.io/2019/03/20/PowerShell-Replace-Operator/

Comment: The key here is the `-match` and `-replace` operators support _regex_ and you need to escape metacharacters like the period.

Answer (score 2):

> `$file.Name -ireplace (".", "")`

**invariably returns an *empty string***, because the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) (`-ireplace` is just an alias<sup>[1]</sup>) operates on [*regexes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) (regular expressions), in which *metacharacter* `.` matches *any* character<sup>[2]</sup>.

Since `-replace` always replaces *all* matches it finds, all characters in the input are replaced with the empty string, yielding an empty string overall, and passing an empty string via `$newName` to the (positionally implied) `-NewName` parameter of `Rename-Item` predictably causes the error message you saw.

To **match a `.` character *verbatim* in a regex**, you must **escape it as `\.`**:

```
$file.Name -replace '\.', '' # Note: no (...) needed; `, ''` optional
```

<sup>Note that it's generally better to use `'...'` quoting rather than `"..."` for regexes and string literals meant to be used verbatim.</sup>

However:

- **This would also remove the `.` char. in the filename *extension***, which is undesired.
- Also, your command can be streamlined and simplified, as the solution below shows.

---

**A concise, single-pipeline solution**:

```
Get-ChildItem -File -Path "C:\XXXX\XXXX\XXXX" -Recurse -Include *.*.* | 
  Rename-Item -NewName { ($_.BaseName -replace '\.') + $_.Extension } -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>

- `-File` limits matching to *files* (not also *directories*).
- `-Include *.*.*` limits matching to file names that contain at least *2* `.` chars.
- Piping the files to rename directly from `Get-ChildItem` to `Rename-Item` allows you to specify the `-NewName` argument as a [delay-bind script block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52807680/45375) (`{ ... }`), which can dynamically derive the new name from the name of the respective input file, using the properties of the [System.IO.FileInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.FileInfo) instances received from `Get-ChildItem`.
- `$_.BaseName -replace '\.'` removes all literal `.` chars. (escaped as `\.` in the context of the [*regex*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions) (regular expression) that the [`-replace` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) operates on) from the file *base* name (the part without the (last) filename *extension*).

  - Note: not specifying a replacement operand is the same as specifying `''`, the empty string, resulting in the effective removal of the matched string; in other words: `... -replace '\.'` is the same as `... -replace '\.', ''`
- `+ $_.Extension` appends the original extension to the modified base name.

---

<sup>[1] `-replace` is case-*insensitive* by default, as all PowerShell operators are; `-ireplace` just makes that fact explicit; there's also the `-creplace` variant, where the `c` indicates that the operation is case-*sensitive*.</sup>

<sup>[2] in *single-line* strings; in *multi-line* strings, `.` by default doesn't match `\n` (newlines), though this can be changed via inline matching option `(?s)` at the start of the regex.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There are a few other issues here. You should filter your `Get-ChildItem` results to return only files by including the `-File` switch.

Your current script will replace the last . before your file's extension which will cause some problems. You need to use the `$File.BaseName` and `$File.Extension` attributes to address this problem.

Substitute `-ireplace` with the `.replace()` method.

Lastly, you need to use the `-like` condition in your If statement. The `-match` condition is used for regexes and will not work correctly here.

```
$files = get-childitem -Recurse -File 
foreach($file in $files) {

    if($file.BaseName -like "*.*") {
        $newName = $file.BaseName.Replace(".","") + $file.Extension
        Rename-Item $file.FullName $newName
        Write-Host "Renamed" $file.Name "to $newName at Location:" $file.FullName
    }
}
```

Comment: would it be cleaner to drop the test for a dot and just use the `.Replace('.', '')` method on all the file names? that method will simply do nothing if there is no dot to replace ... it may not be obvious enuf, tho. [*frown*] i can't make up my mind on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that takes advantage of PowerShell's pipeline (remove the `-WhatIf` after you've tested which files will be renamed).

It also uses a [lookahead regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12116625/408817) to replace all but the last dot in the filename.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse  `
    <# Only select files that have more than one '.' in their name #> `
    | Where-Object { ($_.Name.ToCharArray() | Where-Object {$_ -eq '.'} | Measure-Object ).Count -gt 1 } `
    `
    <# Change the location to the directory and rename so you don't have deal with the directory name #> `
    <# Also, use a lookahead regex to replace all but the last dot. #> `
    | ForEach-Object { Push-Location $_.Directory; Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -replace "\.(?=.*?\.)", "") -Verbose -WhatIf; Pop-Location }
```

Here's a more concise version of the same commands using aliases:

```
dir -r | ?{ ($_.Name.ToCharArray() | ?{ $_ -eq '.' } | measure ).Count -gt 1 } | %{ pushd $_.Directory; ren $_ ($_.Name -replace "\.(?=.*?\.)", "") -v -wh; popd }
```